# Eclipse Plugin, How can I know when IResourceDeltaVisitor ends processing tree nodes?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I wrote an Eclipse Plugin that basically allow a programmer to select a Java source from the Project Explorer and by selecting the corresponding DropDown menu option it will creates an interface .java file based on the one selected.
Everything works fine, but now I need to program the update part of the job.
The update requierement is simple, I need to listen for changes and identify that the sources that have the interface generated have been modified and recreate the interface file.
To do this I wrote a class that implements IResourceChangeListener interface. 
That class looks like:

```
public class DTOChangeListener implements IResourceChangeListener {
    private List<UpdatedUnit> updatedUnits;



    public DTOChangeListener() {
        super();
        this.updatedUnits=new ArrayList<UpdatedUnit>();
    }

    @Override
    public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event) {
        try{
            if(event.getType() == IResourceChangeEvent.POST_CHANGE){
                  event.getDelta().accept(this.buildVisitor());
            }
        }catch(CoreException ex){
               ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    protected IResourceDeltaVisitor buildVisitor(){
        IResourceDeltaVisitor result=new IResourceDeltaVisitor() {

        @Override
        public boolean visit(IResourceDelta resDelta) throws CoreException    {
               String resName=resDelta.getResource().getName();
               if(resName==null || resName.equals("")){
                     return true;
               }
               String[] splits=resName.split("\\.");
               String name = splits[0];
               if(name.contains("PropertyAccess")){
                    return false;
               }
               String interfaceName=name + "PropertyAccess";
               String interfaceFile=interfaceName + ".java";
               IResource res=resDelta.getResource();
               if((res instanceof IFolder) || (res instanceof IProject)){
               // Avoid Folder & Project Nodes
                   return true;
               }
               IProject project=res.getProject();
               if(project!=null){
                  if(project.isNatureEnabled("org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature")){
                     IJavaElement element=JavaCore.create(res);
                     if(element instanceof ICompilationUnit){
                        ICompilationUnit unit=(ICompilationUnit)element;
                        IPath path=res.getProjectRelativePath().removeLastSegments(1);
                        IResource propertyAccess=project.findMember(path.append(interfaceFile));
                        if(propertyAccess!=null){
                           UpdatedUnit updatedUnit=new UpdatedUnit(project, path, unit);
                           updatedUnits.add(updatedUnit);
                           return false;
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
               return true;
        }
      };
      return result;
    }

    public List<UpdatedUnit> getUpdatedUnits() {
           return updatedUnits;
    }
}
```

I add the Listener to the Workspace, now the question I have is:

How can I know when the updatedUnits List is completed in order to proccess the list with my own code?
One posible answer to this question would be, don't worry, the:

```
event.getData().accept(this.buildVisitor());
```

will block until proccessing of the visitor finish.
but at least is not documented like it would.

Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it's documented to **not** block, it blocks.